# Remove row in table according to some criteria

Tags: python, pandas

I have a file with 2 columns

```
Col1 : Cluster number
Col2: Seq name
```

Seq names can have different names:

ex:

```
NP_XXXXXX
YP_XXXXXX
AMN16433
```

etc 
and 
`KQ976470.1:66008-66163(-):Atta_colombica` (`Name:number-number(+ or -):Name1_Name2`)

(there is a lot of different name but I'm interesting in only keeping Cluster where I have at least one seq name in this format: 
(`Name:number-number(+ or -):Name1_Name2`) (so basicaly I can recognize them because only them will have a `+` or `-` in their name)

So I keep a cluster if:
- There is at least one seqname with `+` or `-` in its name AND at least `one other seqname`.

I remove if :

-There is only seqname with `+` or `-` in their name.
-There is only other seqname.

So for the exemple:

```
Cluster1    NP_075076
Cluster1    AMN16433
Cluster1    YP_063711
Cluster1    KQ976470.1:66008-66163(-):Cattus_sylvestris
Cluster1    AJP07295
Cluster1    AMN15329
Cluster2    YP_00999
Cluster2    YP_00989
Cluster2    YP_00971
Cluster2    YP_00988
Cluster2    AJP07295
Cluster3    KI976478.1:66021-66123(-):Canis_lupus
Cluster3    AJP07232
Cluster3    AJP07212
Cluster3    AZ976430.1:66045-66190(+):Cavia_porsellus
Cluster4    AHHYUIIY
Cluster5    AZ976490:66042-66190(-):Felis_porsellus
Cluster5    AA976490:66021-66130(+):Felis_porsellus
```

So I should get:

I remove the `Cluster2` because there is no

```
Cluster1    NP_075076
Cluster1    AMN16433
Cluster1    YP_063711
Cluster1    KQ976470.1:66008-66163(-):Cattus_sylvestris
Cluster1    AJP07295
Cluster1    AMN15329
Cluster3    KI976478.1:66021-66123(-):Canis_lupus
Cluster3    AJP07232
Cluster3    AJP07212
Cluster3    AZ976430.1:66045-66190(+):Cavia_porsellus
```

Where I removed `Cluster2` and `Cluster4 because there is no seqname with either a + or a -.` 
I removed Cluster5 because there is ONLY seqname with either a `+` or a `-` and NO other seqname.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per your description, let's name two columns `name` and `value`. So you need to find list of names where value contains `+` and `-` signs. Then find the list of names where values do not contain those symbols. Then find an intersection of those 2 lists, e.g. find final list of names which present in both above lists. Then you need to filter original dataframe where name is present in your final list.

```
import pandas as pd
import io

data = """Cluster1    NP_075076
Cluster1    AMN16433
Cluster1    YP_063711
Cluster1    KQ976470.1:66008-66163(-):Cattus_sylvestris
Cluster1    AJP07295
Cluster1    AMN15329
Cluster2    YP_00999
Cluster2    YP_00989
Cluster2    YP_00971
Cluster2    YP_00988
Cluster2    AJP07295
Cluster3    KI976478.1:66021-66123(-):Canis_lupus
Cluster3    AJP07232
Cluster3    AJP07212
Cluster3    AZ976430.1:66045-66190(+):Cavia_porsellus
Cluster4    AHHYUIIY
Cluster5    AZ976490:66042-66190(-):Felis_porsellus
Cluster5    AA976490:66021-66130(+):Felis_porsellus"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep="\s+", header=None)

df.columns = ["name", "value"]

list1 = df.loc[df.value.str.contains("[+-]")].name.unique()
list2 = df.loc[~df.value.str.contains("[+-]")].name.unique()


final_list = set(list1).intersection(set(list2))

>>> df.loc[df.name.isin(final_list)]
        name                                        value
0   Cluster1                                    NP_075076
1   Cluster1                                     AMN16433
2   Cluster1                                    YP_063711
3   Cluster1  KQ976470.1:66008-66163(-):Cattus_sylvestris
4   Cluster1                                     AJP07295
5   Cluster1                                     AMN15329
11  Cluster3        KI976478.1:66021-66123(-):Canis_lupus
12  Cluster3                                     AJP07232
13  Cluster3                                     AJP07212
14  Cluster3    AZ976430.1:66045-66190(+):Cavia_porsellus
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also get it online using `regex` as follows

```py
df[df['Cluster'].isin(set(df[df['Name'].str.contains('\+|-')]['Cluster'].unique()).intersection(set(df[~df['Name'].str.contains('\+|-')]['Cluster'].unique())))]
```

Result is

```
    Cluster     Name
0   Cluster1    NP_075076
1   Cluster1    AMN16433
2   Cluster1    YP_063711
3   Cluster1    KQ976470.1:66008-66163(-):Cattus_sylvestris
4   Cluster1    AJP07295
5   Cluster1    AMN15329
11  Cluster3    KI976478.1:66021-66123(-):Canis_lupus
12  Cluster3    AJP07232
13  Cluster3    AJP07212
14  Cluster3    AZ976430.1:66045-66190(+):Cavia_porsellus
```

Comment: Your result is slightly different from OP's desired output.